# Getting the size of current font on console C++

Tags: c++

I'm having some problems with a bit of code. Apparently this returns an error.

`GetCurrentConsoleFont(hOut, TRUE, fontInfo);`

Where hOut is the std output handle and fontInfo is a PCONSOLE_FONT_INFO. It stops the thread and then exits returning -1073741819.

Any ideas?

Here is some code that does the causes the exact same problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

PCONSOLE_FONT_INFO fontInfo;
HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

int main() {
    GetCurrentConsoleFont(hOut, FALSE, fontInfo);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is the `fontInfo` pointing to memory you can write to, address of local variable or self allocated?

Comment: [GetCurrentConsoleFont](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getcurrentconsolefont) is looking for a pointer to fontInfo. I'm surprised you didn't get a compiler error. `GetCurrentConsoleFont(hOut, TRUE, &fontInfo);` And that's my guess as you didn't show how fontInfo is defined.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] instead of just a single line of code with no context.

Comment: The error `-1073741819` is `0xC0000005` in hexadecimal; this is `Access Violation`. Most likely you didn't allocate memory for your font info structure.

Comment: fontInfo points to a local variable. And no, &fontInfo doesn't work.

Comment: You say `fontInfo` points. Please show the definition.

Comment: Ok, you created it on the stack. You must `&fontInfo` what is the error with that?

Comment: I just tested. Define as `CONSOLE_FONT_INFO fontInfo;` and then use `&fontInfo`. works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code your using the `fontInfo` variable which is just an uninitialized pointer. There are two types `CONSOLE_FONT_INFO` and with a capital P in front of it `PCONSOLE_FONT_INFO`.
Look at the following code to understand how to do it correctly.

```
HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
CONSOLE_FONT_INFO fontInfo;

if (!GetCurrentConsoleFont(hOut, TRUE, &fontInfo))
    std::cout << GetLastError() << std::endl;
```

In that example I use a local variable so that the memory is on the stack. To pass a pointer you have to take the address with the address operator `&`.

Another possibility is, to allocate the memory on your own by using the `new` operator. But in that case the memory would lie on the heap and you would have to free the memory by using `delete`. You would pass the pointer directly without taking the address.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. I didn't notice i used PCONSOLE_FONT_INFO. I had too use the normal one.